# How to move data from java InputStream to a char * in c++ with jni?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, inputstream

How can I move the data stored in a java InputStream to a char * in c++ using JNI?

Thanks,
Carlos.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

From java:

```
{
        InputStream inputStream = rcvStream;

        byte[]  inData      = new byte[1024];
        int     bytesRead   = inputStream.read();
        byte[]  actualData  = new byte[bytesRead];
        System.arraycopy(inData, 0, actualData, 0, bytesRead);

        jni.setByteArray(inData, bytesRead);
}
```

From C:

```
{

JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_org_alok_jni_AlokJNI_setByteArray
  (JNIEnv * env, jclass this1, jbyteArray ba, jint len) {
memcpy(my_char_array, ba, len);

}
```

Comment: I have similar question but to pass string ->char* and treat char* as a file somehow?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542458/can-i-create-an-stdifstream-based-on-a-char-rather-than-a-file

Answer (score 5):

This is the java code

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("filename");

int numBytesToRead = 1024;
byte[] inBuffer = new byte[numBytesToRead];
int bytesRead = is.read(inBuffer, 0, numBytesToRead);

decodeAacBytes(inBuffer, bytesRead);
```

and the jni code is

```
jint Java_com_example_test_MainActivity_decodeAacBytes(JNIEnv * env, jobject this, jbyteArray input, jint numBytes)
{
    //copy bytes from java
    jbyte* bufferPtr = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, input, NULL);
    char *inputBytes = malloc(numBytes * sizeof(char));
    memcpy(inputBytes, bufferPtr, numBytes);
    (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, input, bufferPtr, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

The values will now be in the inputBytes array

Comment: `jobject this` will fail to compile in C++ as `this` is a C++ keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you can pass an object like InputStream to JNI, but you can pass a String.

The trick would be getting the char[] in Java, before making the JNI call. You can copy the contents of the InputStream to a ByteArrayOutputStream, get the byte[] from the ByteArrayOutputStream and create the String from the byte[].

Comment: Beware the encoding! java char is a unicode char (UTF-16 internally). c++ char is 1 byte (ie ASCII 0-255). For better compatability, look at using wchar_t instead of char.

Comment: I have similar question please see what you think of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542458/can-i-create-an-stdifstream-based-on-a-char-rather-than-a-file

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Here is how I found out:

```
jclass x = env->FindClass("java/io/InpuStream");
jclass y = env->FindClass("java/util/BitSet");
```

The above are `C++` code behind. When I traced, `x` is `NULL` whereas `y` isn't. Therefore, an `InputStream` could not be materialized in a `C++` `JNI` code. But a `BitSet` can be. I know because I have been using it.