# Can I create an std::ifstream based on a char* rather than a file?

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I am interested in sharing data between Java and C++ so JNI.  Currently all the C++ code expects a file so its all written in terms of std::ifstream.  Rather than writing the files and reading them again, I would like to be able to just pass a char* over and have the application read from that instead somehow treating the char* as a ifstream.  Is there anyway to create a ifstream that is based on a char* ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's called `std::istringstream`.  You can use it like this:

```
#include<sstream>

....

char const* s = "whatever";

std::istringstream iss(std::string(s));

int i;

iss >> i;

....
```

If your code expects a `std::ifstream` *specifically*, you could change it to expect a generic `std::istream`, from which both inherit, as Adrian mentioned.

Comment: so LOL and LOL and LOl oh over 15 char now

Answer (score 2):

Have your thought about using string streams - they often behave like files. Does you code really want an ifstream and not a istream. If it was written with an istream you could just drop in a stringstream/istringstream classes.